# jodatime DateTime.getMillis is in UTC, correct? epoch

Tags: jodatime

So, System.currentTimeMillis returns millis in UTC timezone.  Is DateTime.getmillis the same as nearly all libraries I know the millis since epoch is always in UTC?  Is joda-time the same as well?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> System.currentTimeMillis returns millis in UTC timezone

That's incorrect.  `System.currentTimeMillis` returns a **time interval** (measured in milliseconds), from a particular (well specified, universally) **instant** in time (tA), till other instant in time (tB=the current moment). Both instants are points in the "physical" timeline, they are not related at all with timezones.

The confusion might arise because the "initial" time (tA) is specified as  "January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC" but, that's irrelevant, that's just a way of specifying univocally an instant ('ta' = instant in which the clocks in London marked 00:00 the day January 1') . We could have chosen another origin: for example, tA=the instant in which the Apollo XI landed on the moon. You'll agree that if I define this new epoch: "milliseconds since that instant 'tA' till now", you and I will get the same number (at the same instant) and it would not have anything to do with our timezones.

Comment: hmmm, something is off then, How does DAteTime know which timezone I am in so it can adjust the millis to be from the epoch which was specified as that above statement?

Comment: A Jodatime Datetime consists of a Instant and a Timezone. With that pair (eg: instant=time of apollo XI landing; timezone: Japan) we can translate to a day-month-year represetantion or whatever. If you and I both construct a Datetime (at the same "instant") without specifing the timezone, you and I will have different DateTimes but with the same instant (you and I will get the same value from System.currentTimeMillis). No adjustment needs to be done.

Comment: BTW: the Jodatime abstraction for the "instant" (what System.currentTimeMillis normally represents) is the class Instant

Comment: ooop, I was getting confused with my other question when I added that comment...now I feel dumb, but thanks for the help.